# Why does my Nikon D300 have live view disabled with my 300mm f/4?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, live-view, nikon-d300

Recently I wanted to use the live view with my 300mm f/4 AF-S and when I pressed the shutter it did nothing (live view did not start).

The live view works perfectly with the 24-85mm AF-G f/3.5-4.5 (FX lens as well).

I checked in the manual but did not find any clue if it is a normal behaviour or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I may have your answer. On the D300 and D700, if you are using lenses that have an aperture ring LV is disabled unless a certain menu setting (f7 on a D300, f9 on a D700) is set the correct way ("Sub-command dial OK").

Your 300mm has an aperture ring; your 24-85mm does not.

See:

http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16465/~/d300-%2F-d700-live-view-mode-disabled

for the setup information.

Comment: Great catch. Something really new for me to learn :)

Comment: Thanks this address well my question, but another question remains: I tested with the same settings (driven by aperture ring) with older AI-S lenses and the Live-View is working well with them.

Comment: I think the camera only cares when the lens has an embedded cpu that can tell the camera what the lens characteristics are. AI-S lenses have no cpu, are treated as 'dumb' lenses that, depending on the camera, reduce your metering options to few or none. Non-CPU lenses evidently also don't trigger the LV limitation.

Comment: Then it looks a bit stupid to disable (in this configuration only) the LV for the most recent lenses with ring and cpu, isn't it? The one without CPU are working well in LV.